# C++ type casting for class and pointer

Tags: c++, types, casting

```
class A{
public:
 virtual void foo() {cout << "A::foo" << endl;}
};

class B: public A{
public:
virtual  void foo() {cout << "B::foo" << endl;}
};

int main(void){
 A a;
 B b;
 A acast=(A)B;
 A *apointer=&B;
 acast.foo(); // A::foo
 apointer->foo() //B::foo
 return 0;
}
```

Why does the two prints behave differently?

Comment: Why shouldn't they? You're calling member functions of objects of different types.

Comment: `A acast=(A)b;` doesn't *cast* `b`, it *converts* it.  There's a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A acast=(A)b;` (assuming this is what you actually have) **slices** the object and uses the sliced object to copy-construct an `A`. It's equivalent to `A acast=A(b);`. `acast` is of dynamic and static type `A` - no longer a `B`. It's a completely new object.

`A *apointer=&b;`, by contrast, is a pointer to an object whose dynamic type is `B`. The original `b` object isn't modified, it's just referred to by a pointer to the base type. Since the dynamic type is `B`, the method `foo` from `B` is called (because it's `virtual` and that's how polymorphism works).

Answer (score 3):

object slicing, `A acast=(A)b;` slices B

Answer (score 1):

The first example is an explicit cast the the compiler understand the object to be of type A. In the second example you're just setting the pointer and the compiler still sees the object as being type B.